# Какие члены класса создать в этом задании?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Есть задание

> Разработать класс «Прямоугольник». Определить в нем конструкторы и деструктор,
> перегрузить операцию пересечения прямоугольников (операция “*”), операцию
> вычисления площади прямоугольника, операции сравнения (по площади).Перегрузка операторов должна быть
> выполнена ДВУМЯ способами: использование метода класса и использование
> дружественной функции!
> Какие члены класса создать и каким способом вычислить пересечение прямоугольников. Что должен возвращать этот метод?

Answer (score 0):

Если под членами класса подразумеваются действительно все члены, то я бы сделал так:

**Поля**: координаты двух противоположных углов прямоугольника, каждый типа `std::pair<int, int>`, если мы работаем в целых числах.

**Методы** описаны в задании, но повторю: конструктор, деструктор, `operator*`, операторы `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `<=`, `>=` для площади. И метод с названием, например, `S()`, возвращающий `unsigned int`, если опять же мы в целых числах, который представляет вычисление площади.

Я описал только открытые члены, т.е. интерфейс класса. Реализация целиком зависит от пожеланий и умений автора, то есть всё, что `private`, определите из своих соображений.

P.S. Интерфейс довольно наивный, хотя и исчерпывающий. Его можно ещё долго совершенствовать с целью улучшения стиля кода, например. Я дал лишь изначальный вариант.